# Issue parsing both values in JSON array | PHP

Tags: php

I have the following JSON array, unfortunately the objects are not being nested in a larger parent so I am unsure how to parse the object.

**JSON Array:**

```
[{"name":"Jacob","id":4},{"name":"Mandy","id":3}]
```

Currently I have done the following, which is just echoing `0` and `1`:

```
$json = '[{"name":"Jacob","id":4},{"name":"Mandy","id":3}]';
$assoc = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($assoc as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
}
```

But I would like to access the values of `name` and `id` on every `foreach`, how can the be done?

Comment: `$value` is the object, so youll need `echo $value->id`

Comment: each element is an assoc array, so: `echo $value['name'].PHP_EOL;`

Comment: @felipsmartins can you please take a look at this question? I appreciate your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70735685/how-to-keep-only-unique-objects-in-json-array-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$json = '[{"name":"Jacob","id":4},{"name":"Mandy","id":3}]';
$assoc = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($assoc as $key => $value) {
    $name = $value['name'];
    $id = $value['id'];

    // do whatever you want with $name and $id
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, if you don't mind can you please take a look at my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70735685/how-to-keep-only-unique-objects-in-json-array-php

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $value["id"]." ".$value["name"];
```

should do it (within your loop), just like any associative array values.