# How to keep only unique objects in JSON array | PHP

Tags: php

I have the following JSON array, I would like to adjust the array to only keep unique `name` values, meaning id could be across numerous objects, but name must be unique, overall Tim and Jacob can only be listed once.

```
$data = '
[
  {
    "name": "Jacob",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "Jacob",
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Tim",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Brady",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Tim",
    "id": 1
  }
]';

$array = json_decode($data, TRUE);
$array = array_values( array_unique( $array, SORT_REGULAR ) );
$result = json_encode( $array );
```

The following is what I have currently tried, but it looks at both values in the object, so it leaves them as is.

**Result I am looking for:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Jacob",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "Tim",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Brady",
    "id": 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function which goes through each of the entries in the array and removes them if their name has been seen before.

```php
function array_unique_names($array) {
    // Copy our input as a temporary new array
    $output = $array;
    // Keep track of which names we've seen before
    $seen_names = [];

    foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
        // If we've seen a name before, remove it from our output
        if (in_array($value['name'], $seen_names)) {
            unset($output[$key]);
        }
        // Otherwise, keep it but add it to the list of seen names
        else {
            $seen_names[] = $value['name'];
        }
    }

    // Return a re-indexed array
    return array_values($output);
}

$data = // Your JSON input string

$array = json_decode($data, TRUE);
$array = array_unique_names($array);
$result = json_encode($array);
```